# ElseIf Triggering when it should not

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I am writing a script that allows the user to input a month by either name or number.  In the statement below I can type anything I want into the input box and the line:

```
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "1" Or "2" Or "3" Or "4" Or "5" Or "6" Or "7" Or "8" Or "9" Or "10" Or "11" Or "12" Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber
```

Will always trigger.  I can type "SREGBswerbwergv" into the input box and it will still trigger that line and not move to the "Else" statement.  I restarted excel just in case and it still does it, but not if I comment out that statement.  The complete code:

```
'...and date of report.[BD]
sMonthOfMaintenance = InputBox("What month are you reveiwing?")

'Ending Wizard if Cancelled [BD]
If sMonthOfMaintenance = "" Then

    MsgBox "Operation cancelled"
    End

End If

'Converting Month to Number for Output File Name [BD]
If UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JANUARY" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JAN" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JAN" Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "01"
    ElseIf UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "FEBRUARY" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "FEB" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "FEB." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "02"
    ElseIf UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "MARCH" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "MAR" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "MAR." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "03"
    ElseIf UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "APRIL" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "APR" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "APR." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "04"
    ElseIf UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "MAY" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "MAY." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "05"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "JUNE" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JUN" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JUN." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "06"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "JULY" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JUL" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "JUL." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "07"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "AUGUST" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "AUG" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "AUG." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "08"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "SEPTEMBER" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "SEP" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "SEP." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "09"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "OCTOBER" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "OCT" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "OCT." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "10"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "NOVEMBER" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "NOV" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "NOV." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "11"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "DECEMBER" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "DEC" Or UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance) = "DEC." Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "12"
    ElseIf sMonthOfMaintenance = "01" Or "02" Or "03" Or "04" Or "05" Or "06" Or "07" Or "08" Or "09" Or "10" Or "11" Or "12" Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber
Else
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Valid Month"
    Call Main
End If
```

Comment: You need to repeat the whole condition each time like you have with the others above, e.g., `sMonthOfMaintenance = "01" Or sMonthOfMaintenance = "02"`... As it is now, "02" evaluates to TRUE. Try a `SELECT CASE` instead to shorten the syntax.

Comment: My god, that's the second time I've done that this week.  Thank you!  If you post that as an answer I will check it as correct.

Comment: I think Gary's Student's is a good answer, but I also added mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to repeat the whole condition each time like you have with the others above, e.g., sMonthOfMaintenance = "01" Or sMonthOfMaintenance = "02"... As it is now, "02" evaluates to TRUE. Try a SELECT CASE instead to shorten the syntax. I also see that you try to assign the number to itself towards the end, which I don't think you intended. Here's a sample of all that:

```
Sub test()
Dim sMonthOfMaintenance As String
Dim sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber As String

sMonthOfMaintenance = InputBox("What month are you reveiwing?")

'Ending Wizard if Cancelled [BD]
If sMonthOfMaintenance = "" Then
    MsgBox "Operation cancelled"
    GoTo exit_point
End If

'Converting Month to Number for Output File Name [BD]
Select Case UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance)
   Case "JANUARY", "JAN", "JAN."
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "01"
   Case "FEBRUARY", "FEB", "FEB."
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = "02"
'...
   Case "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = sMonthOfMaintenance
   Case Else
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Valid Month"
    'Call Main
End Select
Debug.Print sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber
exit_point:
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this solution is the best one because it is easy to see the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any ***If()***.  Just convert the text-month to a date and get the number-month from that:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim sMonthOfMaintenance As String
    Dim sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber As String

    sMonthOfMaintenance = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter month name ", Type:=2)

    sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = Format(Month(DateValue("1 " & Left(UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance), 3) & " 1992")), "00")

    MsgBox sMonthOfMaintenance & vbCrLf & sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber
End Sub
```

[image]

You can enter any of the following:

jan
JAN
jan.
JAN.
JANUARY
january

If you want to also allow the entry of month-by-number, then a separate branch must be added to test for a numeric entry:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim sMonthOfMaintenance As String
    Dim sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber As String

    sMonthOfMaintenance = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter month name ", Type:=2)

    If IsNumeric(sMonthOfMaintenance) Then
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = Format(CLng(sMonthOfMaintenance), "00")
    Else
        sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber = Format(Month(DateValue("1 " & Left(UCase(sMonthOfMaintenance), 3) & " 1992")), "00")
    End If

    MsgBox sMonthOfMaintenance & vbCrLf & sMonthOfMaintenanceNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  I up-voted your answer for the information.  But will this also accept "Feb" and "Feb." like my if statement does above?

Comment: It **should** accept any of the following:  *FEB,feb,FEB.,feb.,FEBRUARY,February,february*, etc..............if it fails, let me know and will try to fix it.

Comment: Wow, awesome.  Thanks, Gary's Student!